# 230 VAC 16 A relay Circuit for Reduced EMI

Tags: transistors, filter, emc, emi-filtering, latching-relay

I am designing a PCB that will needs EMI testing from a laboratory. I have a 230 VAC 16 A relay in PCB. I am not sure will it cause EMI issues while switching between loads or not. If anyone as better suggestion to design the circuit in a certain way or current design is ok?
Relay datasheet: https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2201180700_Phoenix-Contact-2961312_C1526007.pdf
[image: Schematic]

Comment: It won't *need* testing as far as I can see. Why do you think it will? What might generate the EMI (your circuit or the undisclosed load that takes up to 16 amps on a 230 volt supply)?

Comment: I think Noise can generate when Switching between NO and NC loads. Since its very high load. I suspect that it can cause EMI issues and noise can disturb nearby signals as there are lot of other components in pcb aswell. If EMI test clears then it will be used in a commercial device.

Comment: anyelse has any comment on it?

Comment: You really should draw relays as a coil + contacts or otherwise the schematic symbol isn't very helpful.

Comment: The datasheet you linked uses a coil of 24V yet in your schematic you supply it with 5V. That will obviously not work. As for EMC, it is pointless to discuss without the PCB layout.

Comment: I'll attach PCB Files here in few days as layout is still in progress